# What is the correct context for bpy.ops.uv's?

Tags: python

I'm trying to unwrap a new mesh using bmesh, but am receiving this error "RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.uv.smart_project.poll() failed, context is incorrect"

I've looked around for a solution but have found none. What is the correct context for this operator, and what is the preferred way to change it? (I've seen a with statement and looks like the context can be changed as a parameter in the method)

Some relevant code:

```
obj: Object = bpy.data.objects.get('Step One')
obj.select_set(True)
        
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

current_context = bpy.context.copy()
for x, y in current_context.items():
    print(x, ':', y)

# Problem here
bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=66, island_margin=0.02)
```

Here is the console report on the context:

```
active_action : None
active_annotation_layer : None
active_bone : None
active_editable_fcurve : None
active_gpencil_frame : None
active_gpencil_layer : None
active_nla_strip : None
active_nla_track : None
active_object : <bpy_struct, Object("Step One") at 0x130483a08>
active_operator : None
active_pose_bone : None
active_sequence_strip : None
annotation_data : None
annotation_data_owner : <bpy_struct, Scene("Scene") at 0x1300e3608>
area : <bpy_struct, Area at 0x11706faa8>
asset : None
asset_library_reference : <bpy_struct, AssetLibraryReference at 0x1170563b8>
blend_data : <bpy_struct, BlendData at 0x1300c6408>
collection : <bpy_struct, Collection("Scene Collection") at 0x117093ac8>
edit_object : <bpy_struct, Object("Step One") at 0x130483a08>
editable_bones : None
editable_fcurves : None
editable_gpencil_layers : None
editable_gpencil_strokes : None
editable_objects : [bpy.data.objects['Step One']]
engine : CYCLES
evaluated_depsgraph_get : <bpy_func Context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()>
gizmo_group : None
gpencil_data : None
gpencil_data_owner : None
image_paint_object : None
layer_collection : <bpy_struct, LayerCollection("Scene Collection") at 0x117093a78>
mode : EDIT_MESH
object : <bpy_struct, Object("Step One") at 0x130483a08>
objects_in_mode : [bpy.data.objects['Step One']]
objects_in_mode_unique_data : [bpy.data.objects['Step One']]
particle_edit_object : None
pose_object : None
preferences : <bpy_struct, Preferences at 0x10e668dc8>
property : None
region : <bpy_struct, Region at 0x117071c48>
region_data : <bpy_struct, RegionView3D at 0x117071e08>
scene : <bpy_struct, Scene("Scene") at 0x1300e3608>
screen : <bpy_struct, Screen("Modeling") at 0x1170647f8>
sculpt_object : None
selectable_objects : [bpy.data.objects['Step One']]
selected_bones : None
selected_editable_actions : None
selected_editable_bones : None
selected_editable_fcurves : None
selected_editable_keyframes : None
selected_editable_objects : [bpy.data.objects['Step One']]
selected_editable_sequences : []
selected_ids : [bpy.data.objects['Step One']]
selected_movieclip_tracks : None
selected_nla_strips : None
selected_objects : [bpy.data.objects['Step One']]
selected_pose_bones : None
selected_pose_bones_from_active_object : None
selected_sequences : []
selected_visible_actions : None
selected_visible_fcurves : None
sequences : []
space_data : <bpy_struct, SpaceView3D at 0x1300c7e08>
tool_settings : <bpy_struct, ToolSettings at 0x11708e4f8>
ui_list : None
vertex_paint_object : None
view_layer : <bpy_struct, ViewLayer("View Layer") at 0x1170936e8>
visible_bones : None
visible_fcurves : None
visible_gpencil_layers : None
visible_objects : [bpy.data.objects['Step One']]
visible_pose_bones : None
weight_paint_object : None
window : <bpy_struct, Window at 0x117054d88>
window_manager : <bpy_struct, WindowManager("WinMan") at 0x1300c6c08>
workspace : <bpy_struct, WorkSpace("Modeling") at 0x117056298>
```

What in this context is smart_project complaining about?

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.uv.smart_project.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

Update: None of the uv's poll correctly: bpy.ops.uv.align() and others fail.

Comment: your script worked for me

Comment: That's disappointing. Any thought as to why my code is not, but yours is?